# Encountering a “No route to host” error when trying to access my Elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, networking, kibana, performance-testing

I have a elastic search cluster installed in my Azure Virtual machine (linux) with private ip
10.176.83.156 and the elasticsearch.yml file have following values

```
cluster.name: Test-cluster
node.name: node-1
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
# Create a new cluster with the current node only
# Additional nodes can still join the cluster later
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["l01q23705150001"]

# Allow HTTP API connections from anywhere
# Connections are encrypted and require user authentication
http.host: 0.0.0.0
```

I'm able to access the elastic search from inside the linux machine(10.176.83.156) from where it is installed.

```
curl -u elastic:NYC59UxNJ3FRNZUpNhKa https://10.176.83.156:9200 -k
  {
  "name" : "l01q23705150001",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "wOepv5C_T3md3a0K6f1yOw",
  "version" : {
  "number" : "8.12.2",
  "build_flavor" : "default",
  "build_type" : "rpm",
  "build_hash" : "48a287ab9497e852de30327444b0809e55d46466",
  "build_date" : "2024-02-19T10:04:32.774273190Z",
  "build_snapshot" : false,
  "lucene_version" : "9.9.2",
  "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
  "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
    },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
  }
```

But accessing it from outside from my local machine with VPN I'm getting error

```
curl -u elastic:NYC59UxNJ3FRNZUpNhKa https://10.176.83.156:9200 -k
   curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.192.85.168 port 9200: No route to host 
enter code here
```

Also added the following inbound rules to the Linux machine's NSG.

[image]

Comment: You can’t access 10.*.*.* addresses from outside. Off topic.

Comment: I’am accessing it using a VPN, sir :-( . Please remove the down vote if you did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the error I had to add the following rule to the Linux server's local firewall

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=9200/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

An error message suggests a routing problem. Are you sure that Azure VPN has been configured correctly? If so, are you able to connect to the same machine via VPN to this server after SSH or connect to any other service configured on this server?
As an additional test, create a new machine in the same subnet and try to connect to Elasticsearch to make sure that the Elasticsearch service responds to requests from outside localhost
Performing these checks can help find the cause of the problem or at least narrow the scope